# Hide WooCommerce sale prices for logged-out user

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, product

I'm using the WooCommerce product table plugin by Barn2, this plugin allows you to add custom columns so I added a custom column to display "SALE PRICE" in a separate column using **_sale_price** custom field. The sale price gets displayed and I want to hide that sale price column data for non-logged-in customers, although regular prices are hidden for non-logged-in customers using the Wholesale pro plugin(By Barn2) Now, I'm struggling to find a solution to hide the sale price column for non-logged-in customers. I attempted this code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_sale_price', function( $price ) {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return '';
    }

    return $price; // Return original price
} );
```

Comment: Did you try with `get_post_meta()`?

Comment: @MainulHasan I'm not sure about that, how we can use get_post_meta().

Comment: Just go here - https://barn2.com/support-center/

Comment: @MartinMirchev Thank you for the suggestion. Already submitted the ticket.

Comment: @Minhas no problem. Just keep in mind those are premium plugins and here most of the ppl prob wont have them and your chance someone to help you is realy low.  Try this solution without the filters if you want only to hide the price - https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-hide-price-add-cart-logged-users/